# Reuse existing objects for immutable objects?

Tags: python, immutability

In Python, how is it possible to reuse existing equal immutable objects (like is done for `str`)? Can this be done just by defining a `__hash__` method, or does it require more complicated measures?

Comment: +1 Interesting question.  I know for strings the process is called "interning" but I'm not sure if that term is specifically for strings, as I've never heard of anything else getting interned.

Comment: Often the hash function will be implemented as the address of the object, so you get a chicken/egg problem; the hash won't be equal until you've already decided the objects are the same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to create via the class constructor and have it return a previously created object then you will need to provide a `__new__` method (because by the time you get to `__init__` the object has already been created).

Here is a simple example - if the value used to initialise has been seen before then a previously created object is returned rather than a new one created:

```
class Cached(object):
    """Simple example of immutable object reuse."""

    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __new__(cls, i, _cache={}):
        try:
            return _cache[i]
        except KeyError:
            # you must call __new__ on the base class
            x = super(Cached, cls).__new__(cls)
            x.__init__(i)
            _cache[i] = x
            return x
```

Note that for this example you can use anything to initialise as long as it's hashable. And just to show that objects really are being reused:

```
>>> a = Cached(100)
>>> b = Cached(200)
>>> c = Cached(100)
>>> a is b
False
>>> a is c
True
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked, the only difference I used was like so: `class a(object): _cached = {} <then the rest>`. The reason I did it this way is because I think instantiating  objects in function parameters can be confusing, because in some cases people may not realize that it is being instantiated only once, and that it refers to the same object for all the calls of that function.

Comment: @Abafei: Yes, your change is a good one. A lot of people like to avoid mutable default arguments as they often confuse others - I'm not quite so considerate :)

Comment: Note that `__init__` will be called *twice* when there is a cache miss and once if there's a cache hit. You need to explicitly protect against multiple constructor calls e.g. set a flag at the end of `__init__` and return immediately if the flag is set.

Answer (score 4):

There are two 'software engineering' solutions to this that don't require any low-level knowledge of Python. They apply in the following scenarios:

**First Scenario:** Objects of your class are 'equal' if they are constructed with the same constructor parameters, and equality won't change over time after construction. *Solution:* Use a factory that hashses the constructor parameters:

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, someint, someotherint):
    self.a = someint
    self.b = someotherint

cachedict = { }
def construct_myobject(someint, someotherint):
  if (someint, someotherint) not in cachedict:
    cachedict[(someint, someotherint)] = MyClass(someint, someotherint)
  return cachedict[(someint, someotherint)]
```

This approach essentially limits the instances of your class to one unique object per distinct input pair. There are obvious drawbacks as well: not all types are easily hashable and so on.

**Second Scenario:** Objects of your class are mutable and their 'equality' may change over time. *Solution:* define a class-level registry of equal instances:

```
class MyClass:
  registry = { }

  def __init__(self, someint, someotherint, third):
    MyClass.registry[id(self)] = (someint, someotherint)
    self.someint = someint
    self.someotherint = someotherint
    self.third = third

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return MyClass.registry[id(self)] == MyClass.registry[id(other)]

  def update(self, someint, someotherint):
    MyClass.registry[id(self)] = (someint, someotherint)
```

In this example, objects with the same `someint, someotherint` pair are equal, while the third parameter does not factor in. The trick is to keep the parameters in `registry` in sync. As an alternative to `update`, you could override `getattr` and `setattr` for your class instead; this would ensure that any assignment `foo.someint = y` would be kept synced with your class-level dictionary. See an example [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/389916-example-setattr-getattr-overloading/).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you would have to keep a dict {args: object} of instances already created, then override the class' `__new__` method to check in that dictionary, and return the relevant object if it already existed. Note that I haven't implemented or tested this idea. Of course, strings are handled at the C level.

Comment: Yes this works - I've successfully used this method before. I may post some example code tomorrow if no one beats me to it.